# SSRS : Table Break Issue

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, export, localreport

I've used table in `SSRS` report and when I export it in `pdf` format then the table comes in half page and rest of table comes in second page. First half page is blank.

See image:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Report -> Report Properties and then change the Paper size Width and Height

Comment: it worked for me thanks.. :) i just forgot to mark it as answer..so marking it now..